# Move users with Feed Me

Tags: users, password, plugin-feedme

Is it possible to move users along with their passwords? I can see the mapping option, but how do I output password in a template (I'm moving data between craft installations).

The below code does not work.

```
{% for user in craft.users().status(null).all() %}
    <password>{{user.password}}</password>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password hashes aren't included in the default user query for security reasons, but if you want to force them to get added, you could use:

```
{% for user in craft.users().status(null).addSelect(['users.password']).all() %}
```

Comment: I also need to migrate 800+ users and passwords from C2 to C3. I've got the following but password is blank each time. ```{% for user in craft.users.group('publicUsers').addSelect(['users.password']) %}
  <password>{{ user.password }}</password>
{% endfor %}```

Comment: @CreateSean did you figure this out?